# Copy files and directories without files content

Tags: command-line

Is there a way to copy directory structure with files but without their contents. I mean that I want exactly the same directories with files names but leaving them blank/empty. I have few example applications in some programming language and I want to rewrite them with my own style but keeping the way that they was organised in files.

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From `man cp`

> --attributes-only
>                 don't copy the file data, just the attributes

So , if you want to copy all folders and files that are in `somedirectory`

do  `cp -R --attributes-only somedirectory  destinationdirectory`

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you very much.

Comment: +1 because I didn't think someone had already implemented this - really surprised.

Comment: @mgarciaisaia I was just surprised as you are, when I checked the man page this morning =)

Answer (score 10):

Nice that Ubuntu `cp` has this feature, but if you should find yourself on a machine that doesn't (BSD-style `cp` does not, for example, so OS X does not either), it's very easy to do with `find`. Here it is as a two-liner (for readability):

```
% cd original_dir
% find . -type d -exec mkdir -p ../copy_dir/{} \;
% find . -type f -exec touch ../copy_dir/{} \;
```

If `copy_dir` already exists, you can skip the `-p` argument to `mkdir` since `find` will traverse the directory tree top-down. For large jobs, you can shave off another millisecond or so by terminating the commands with `+` instead of `\;` if your `find` supports it (it probably does).

**Edit:** The above commands neglected to handle symbolic links, which can be copied with a third run of `find` (**do not** terminate this one with `+`):

```
% find . -type l -exec cp -R {} ../copy_dir/{} \;
```